# Extract number of pixels from a cropped region

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I was hoping to find out the number of pixels in a specific region from a pretty dark image , but cant find the right way. Can I please get some help.

[image]

I was trying to crop the image along the two red boundaries and then draw a white line over the red line and count nonzero pixels over it. But i think its a pretty ugly approach.

My end goal : It is to find the pixel to mm ratio (1 block between two red lines is 1.891mm)

P.S - It may sound a little silly to ask but i had a question too , if i zoom in to the image , does the number of pixels in a fixed region change than the original state(i believe they dont, not sure) while resizing does affects the number of pixels in a region right ?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: "crop the distance" ???

Comment: Interactively or automatically ?

Comment: Hi , not interactively , just automatically

Answer (score 1):

The red line stands out from the background. Pick its color and mark every pixel of a similar color. This should result in a binary image with only the scale.

Then follow the horizontal line from left to right, preferring horizontal moves over diagonal ones. Then determine the local width by means of vertical displacements. The maxima of the width will reveal the positions of the tick marks.

You can probably refine the measurements and resort to subpixel analysis, but this is another story.